# How do I add a _Load Event to a control - with a twist

Tags: c#, user-controls

In C#, I want to add a _ResizeEnd event to a DataGridView control.  I have found some code to help with this (that allows adding a _ResizeEnd event to a usercontrol).

```
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
((Form)this.Parent).ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(UserControl1_ResizeEnd);
}
void UserControl1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Resize end");
}
```

As noted, I want to adapt this to add the event to a DataGridView.  What I could do is create a UserControl and dump a DataGridView control onto it, and implement the _ResizeEnd event as per the code above.

However, the problem with that is that I want all the properties, methods and events of the DataGridView to remain exposed in the designer.  I am not aware of an "easy" method of exposing them (i.e. exposing the child control methods etc to the parent usercontrol), aside from writing all the Get/Set / events / methods etc.

I thought I could change the inheritance from:
    public partial class MyDataGridView : UserControl
To:
    public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView

This solves the problem of having all the DataGridView properties etc exposed to the usercontrol, but of course this doesn't move me forward, because the DataGridView class (unlike the UserControl Class), doesn't have a _Load event.

So....
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
By the way... I understood that SubClassing would be:

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
```

This does expose the DataGridView properties etc, but I lose the : UserControl inheritance, meaning that there is no _Load event exposed.

I'm not sure how to inherit both the UserControl properties / methods and the DataGridView properties etc.

Comment: If you want to know about the parent, like you do here, then you want the ParentChanged event, not the Load event.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to set the `ResizeEnd` inside a `Load` event? Why not subclass `DataGridView` (which is the best way to get all of the existing properties and events) and then setup the event handler inside `MyDataGridView`? Since all you want is the Parent, I recommend reacting to the `ParentChanged` event. The below works for me (note that I don't believe the Parent will ever change, but people can do funky things :) ):

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    private Form _curParent;

    public CustomDataGridView()
    {
        // Since Parent is not set yet, handle the event that tells us that it *is* set
        this.ParentChanged += CustomDataGridView_ParentChanged;
    }

    void CustomDataGridView_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent is Form)
        {
            // be nice and remove the event from the old parent
            if (_curParent != null)
            {
                _curParent.ResizeEnd -= CustomDataGridView_ResizeEnd;
            }

            // now update _curParent to the new Parent
            _curParent = (Form)this.Parent;

            _curParent.ResizeEnd += CustomDataGridView_ResizeEnd;
        }
    }

    void CustomDataGridView_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resize End called on parent. React now!");
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know (I'm not an expert!), if you put it in the constructor, then the problem happens that the control has not been loaded when the constructor is called, therefore it doesn't have a parent (form) that you can catch the `ResizeEnd` event from.  By using the `load` event, the control will have a parent.  Thanks for the info on subclassing.  Not sure how to do that (have only done it previously in Visual Basic 6).  I'll research it.

Comment: OK - thanks.  That code works great, although I have found another issue...  It works nicely when the `CustomDataGridView` is placed directly onto a form.  It doesn't work when the control is placed in another container on the form.  I tried to use a recursive approach to iterate up the parent hierarchy to find the Form at the top of the tree, but that doesn't work for some reason, because at the time of the `ParentChanged` event, the Parent is apparently Null (go figure...) `while (!(parentForm is Form)){    parentForm = parentForm.Parent;}`  (Sorry-no pretty formatting in these comments!)

Comment: It won't work because of the ordering of placement. First the `Grid` is added to the container and then that container is added to the Form. 2 options:

1. Add a handler to the ParentChanged of the Parent until you reach the form (kind gross)
2. use a different callback. For example, remove the callback to ParentChanged and instead use:


        protected override void OnInvalidated(InvalidateEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInvalidated(e);
        }

in there find (and cache! Otherwise your perf will take a hit) the Parent and set the handler.

Answer (score 0):

OK - thanks for all your help.  Final working code is as below (open to suggestions if it needs refinement!)

```
 public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        private Form _curParent = null;
        protected override void OnInvalidated(InvalidateEventArgs e) 
        {
            //Exit if no parent, or _curParent already set.
            if (Parent == null || _curParent != null) return;

            base.OnInvalidated(e);

            //Recurse until parent form is found:
            Control parentForm = Parent;

            while (!(parentForm is Form))
            {
                if (parentForm.Parent == null) return;  //Break if this is a null - indicates parent not yet created.
                parentForm = parentForm.Parent; 
            }

            //Have now found parent form at the top of the ancestor tree.
            // be nice and remove the event from the old parent
            if (_curParent != null)
            {
                _curParent.ResizeEnd -= MyDataGridView_ResizeEnd;
            }
            // now update _curParent to the new Parent
            _curParent = (Form)parentForm;

            //Add the resized event handler
            _curParent.ResizeEnd += MyDataGridView_ResizeEnd;

        }


        void MyDataGridView_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resize End called on parent. React now!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice! A couple of comments: 1. base.OnInvalidated needs to be called always, so that needs to go first (actually, I'd put the whole detection logic in an if and call base last in case invalidate causes a resize) 2. the second `(_curParent != null)` check is invalid since that can never be true (you "return" above if this is true). You might not care about this case if you aren't moving the Grid dynamically.